# dataweave 1.0 to 2.0 migration in mulesoft

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I'm trying to convert the below dataweave from 1.0 to 2.0, but everything I've tried gives the following errors like evaluating-expression Error, Invalid input "reduce" and replace.

Mule 3 Dataweave 1.0:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
%var basicPolicy = payload.DTOApplication.DTOBasicPolicy
%var insuredInfo = payload.DTOApplication.DTOInsured
%var insuredPrimaryAddr = insuredInfo.*PartyInfo[?($.@PartyTypeCd == "InsuredParty")].*Addr[?($.@AddrTypeCd == "InsuredPrimaryBusAddr")][0]
%var lineLiability = payload.DTOApplication.*DTOLine[?($.@StatusCd == "Active" and $.@LineCd == "Liability")][0]
%var lineProperty = payload.DTOApplication.*DTOLine[?($.@StatusCd == "Active" and $.@LineCd == "CommercialProperty")][0]
%var lineProductLiability = payload.DTOApplication.*DTOLine[?($.@StatusCd == "Active" and $.@LineCd == "ProductLiability")][0]
%var primaryClassTotalExposure = lineLiability.*DTORisk[?($.@Status == "Active" and $.@TypeCd == "Exposure")].*DTOGLClass[?($.@GLClassCode == primaryExposure)].@Exposure default [] reduce ((val,acc=0) -> acc + (val replace "\$" with "" replace "," with "") as :number)
%var primaryClassPLTotalExposure = lineProductLiability.*DTORisk[?($.@Status == "Active" and $.@TypeCd == "Exposure")].*DTOGLClass[?($.@GLClassCode == primaryExposurePL)].@Exposure default [] reduce ((val,acc=0) -> acc + (val replace "\$" with "" replace "," with "") as :number)
---
{
    
    Policy: {
        PolType: basicPolicy.@SubTypeCd default "",
        Zip: insuredPrimaryAddr.@PostalCode[0..4] default "",
        EffDate: basicPolicy.@EffectiveDt default "",
        ExpDate: basicPolicy.@ExpirationDt default "",
        EBCov: lineProperty.@EquipmentBreakdown default "No",
        PolFeeOR2: payload.DTOApplication.*DTOFee[?($.@Status == "Active" and $.@RateDRCFeeInd == "No")][0].@FullTermAmt default "",
        PolFeeOR: (payload.DTOApplication.DTOFeeOverrides.*DTOFeeOverride[?($.@Code == "POLF" and $.@OverrideInd == "Yes")][0].@Amount default "") when payload.DTOApplication.DTOFeeOverrides.*DTOFeeOverride[?($.@Code == "POLF" and $.@OverrideInd == "Yes")][0].@Amount != null
                    otherwise (payload.DTOApplication.*DTOFee[?($.@Status == "Active" and $.@RateDRCFeeInd == "No")][0].@FullTermAmt default "")  when payload.DTOApplication.*DTOFee[?($.@Status == "Active" and $.@RateDRCFeeInd == "No")][0].@FullTermAmt != null
                    otherwise "",
        LiabExp: primaryClassTotalExposure,
        ProdExp: primaryClassPLTotalExposure
    }   
}
```

Input payload : https://github.com/Manikandan99/rate-dtostep/blob/master/request.xml

Expected output: https://github.com/Manikandan99/rate-dtostep/blob/master/policy_response.xml

I tried dataweave 2.0:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
var basicPolicy = payload.DTOApplication.DTOBasicPolicy
var insuredInfo = payload.DTOApplication.DTOInsured
var insuredPrimaryAddr = insuredInfo.*PartyInfo[?($.@PartyTypeCd == "InsuredParty")].*Addr[?($.@AddrTypeCd == "InsuredPrimaryBusAddr")][0]
var lineLiability = payload.DTOApplication.*DTOLine[?($.@StatusCd == "Active" and $.@LineCd == "Liability")][0]
var lineProperty = payload.DTOApplication.*DTOLine[?($.@StatusCd == "Active" and $.@LineCd == "CommercialProperty")][0]
var lineProductLiability = payload.DTOApplication.*DTOLine[?($.@StatusCd == "Active" and $.@LineCd == "ProductLiability")][0]
var primaryClassTotalExposure = lineLiability.*DTORisk[?($.@Status == "Active" and $.@TypeCd == "Exposure")].*DTOGLClass[?($.@GLClassCode == primaryExposure)].@Exposure default [] reduce ((val,acc=0) -> acc + (val replace "\$" with "" replace "," with "") as :number)
var primaryClassPLTotalExposure = lineProductLiability.*DTORisk[?($.@Status == "Active" and $.@TypeCd == "Exposure")].*DTOGLClass[?($.@GLClassCode == primaryExposurePL)].@Exposure default [] reduce ((val,acc=0) -> acc + (val replace "\$" with "" replace "," with "") as :number)
---
{
    
    Policy: {
        PolType: basicPolicy.@SubTypeCd default "",
        Zip: insuredPrimaryAddr.@PostalCode[0 to 4] default "",
        EffDate: basicPolicy.@EffectiveDt default "",
        ExpDate: basicPolicy.@ExpirationDt default "",
        EBCov: lineProperty.@EquipmentBreakdown default "No",
        PolFeeOR2: payload.DTOApplication.*DTOFee[?($.@Status == "Active" and $.@RateDRCFeeInd == "No")][0].@FullTermAmt default "",
        PolFeeOR: (payload.DTOApplication.DTOFeeOverrides.*DTOFeeOverride[?($.@Code == "POLF" and $.@OverrideInd == "Yes")][0].@Amount default "") when payload.DTOApplication.DTOFeeOverrides.*DTOFeeOverride[?($.@Code == "POLF" and $.@OverrideInd == "Yes")][0].@Amount != null
                    otherwise (payload.DTOApplication.*DTOFee[?($.@Status == "Active" and $.@RateDRCFeeInd == "No")][0].@FullTermAmt default "")  when payload.DTOApplication.*DTOFee[?($.@Status == "Active" and $.@RateDRCFeeInd == "No")][0].@FullTermAmt != null
                    otherwise "",
        LiabExp: primaryClassTotalExposure,
        ProdExp: primaryClassPLTotalExposure 
    }   
}
```

Any ideas please on how to write the same in dataweave 2.0?

Comment: while posting a question, stackoverflow doesn't allows to post more code in the question. Therefore, I used git links in the question. Please Refer it..

Comment: you should not use when and otherwise in mule4 (in mule4 we use if and else), also i saw that you are using as :number that is completely wrong, in mule4 use (as Number). just try to search if else in mule4 documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding few more points to @AnuragSharma's comments

[if-else-if](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-flow-control#control_flow_if_else)

1. In your dw you have `GLClassCode == primaryExposure` , **primaryExposure** is not present in your input payload hence this will result in a null value and you cant use `replace` function along with null
2. Since you are trying to cast to number , you can give a `default` value. Here I have set it to 0.
3. Added `encoding="UTF-8"` as required in output

To test your code I have passed **GLClasscode as CANDIS** as you had that in your payload.

**Note** - > Please check your parenthesis as well.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml encoding="UTF-8"
var basicPolicy = payload.DTOApplication.DTOBasicPolicy
var insuredInfo = payload.DTOApplication.DTOInsured
var insuredPrimaryAddr = insuredInfo.*PartyInfo[?($.@PartyTypeCd == "InsuredParty")].*Addr[?($.@AddrTypeCd == "InsuredPrimaryBusAddr")][0]
var lineLiability = payload.DTOApplication.*DTOLine[?($.@StatusCd == "Active" and $.@LineCd == "Liability")][0]
var lineProperty = payload.DTOApplication.*DTOLine[?($.@StatusCd == "Active" and $.@LineCd == "CommercialProperty")][0]
var lineProductLiability = payload.DTOApplication.*DTOLine[?($.@StatusCd == "Active" and $.@LineCd == "ProductLiability")][0]
var primaryClassTotalExposure = lineLiability.*DTORisk[?($.@Status == "Active" and $.@TypeCd == "Exposure")].*DTOGLClass[?($.@GLClassCode == "CANDIS")].@Exposure default [] reduce ($$++$) replace "\$" with "" replace "," with "" default 0  as Number
var primaryClassPLTotalExposure = lineProductLiability.*DTORisk[?($.@Status == "Active" and $.@TypeCd == "Exposure")].*DTOGLClass[?($.@GLClassCode == "CANDIS")].@Exposure default []  reduce ($$++$) replace "\$" with "" replace "," with "" default 0 as Number
---
{
    
    Policy: {
        PolType: basicPolicy.@SubTypeCd default "",
        Zip: insuredPrimaryAddr.@PostalCode[0 to 4] default "",
        EffDate: basicPolicy.@EffectiveDt default "",
        ExpDate: basicPolicy.@ExpirationDt default "",
        EBCov: lineProperty.@EquipmentBreakdown default "No",
        PolFeeOR2: payload.DTOApplication.*DTOFee[?($.@Status == "Active" and $.@RateDRCFeeInd == "No")][0].@FullTermAmt default "",
        PolFeeOR: if (payload.DTOApplication.DTOFeeOverrides.*DTOFeeOverride[?($.@Code == "POLF" and $.@OverrideInd == "Yes")][0].@Amount != null)
                        (payload.DTOApplication.DTOFeeOverrides.*DTOFeeOverride[?($.@Code == "POLF" and $.@OverrideInd == "Yes")][0].@Amount default "") 
                else if (payload.DTOApplication.*DTOFee[?($.@Status == "Active" and $.@RateDRCFeeInd == "No")][0].@FullTermAmt != null)
                    (payload.DTOApplication.*DTOFee[?($.@Status == "Active" and $.@RateDRCFeeInd == "No")][0].@FullTermAmt default "")  
                    else "",
        LiabExp: primaryClassTotalExposure,
        ProdExp: primaryClassPLTotalExposure 
    }   
}
```

Output

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Policy>
  <PolType>CNPK</PolType>
  <Zip>80003</Zip>
  <EffDate>20211117</EffDate>
  <ExpDate>20221117</ExpDate>
  <EBCov>Yes</EBCov>
  <PolFeeOR2/>
  <PolFeeOR/>
  <LiabExp>2000000</LiabExp>
  <ProdExp>0</ProdExp>
</Policy>
```